# To which age this currency belong?

Tags: roman-empire, currency, money

My freind sent me thise picture and he is asking to which age this currency  belong
[image: face2]

[image]

Comment: What did Google say?

Comment: Might be [this](http://numistories.com/912/constantine-ii-a-question-of-seniority/). What's on the other side?

Comment: I will attach it

Answer (score 3):

This was minted between 337AD and 340AD under Constantine II

[Coin for sale](http://www.cerberuscoins.com/constantine-ii-gloria-exercitvs-antioch-mint.html)

[Forum where the Experts are](http://www.coincommunity.com/forum/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=104858)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the backside looks to be a close as well, so it looks similar to the coin displayed on the page [NumiStories](http://numistories.com/912/constantine-ii-a-question-of-seniority/). According to this page:

> This particular follis was struck in 332 A.D. at the Lugdunum mint,
>   known today as Lyons, France. The portrait shows a young Constantine
>   II facing right in military cuirass and crowned with a laurel wreath
>   denoting his rank as Caesar.

If this is the same, that means this coin depicts [Constantine II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constantine_II_(emperor)), and dates to the 3rd century, Roman Empire.

Comment: I'm suspicious of your numi link, could be my own ignorance but the writing on the side with the "tails" side has different markings at the bottom.

Comment: @ EvanM Agreed on the writing, edited by answer.The back side of the first coin you link to looks off as well.

Comment: Yep... I was looking more too. Looks like it might signify the mint it came from.